# Deserialize JSON into container with polymorphic types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class that just has a few members of polymorphic types. It's not a container in the sense of a collection like a List, just a class.

```
public class Stuff {
    public BaseClassA MyA;
    public BaseClassB MyB;
}
```

Of course BaseClassA and BaseClassB can have various subclasses. I need to be able to serialize and deserialize these to JSON. I've been using Json.NET.

I want to avoid including type information. For the simple case, let's say that whenever I want to deserialize, I know what concrete class each of MyA and MyB will be. But how do I inform Json.NET of my knowledge? I think `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>` won't work, because it will try to create instances of BaseClassA and BaseClassB instead of the subclasses MyA and MyB were originally.

I can think of a few answers. I'm looking for a better answer. For clarity about what I'm asking for, I'll give an example or two of how I could think to do it.

I can have a generic static method on `Stuff`

```
public static Stuff DeserializeMyStuff<TA, TB>(string json) where TA: BaseClassA where TB: BaseClassB
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    BaseClassA a = serializer.Deserialize<TA>(obj["MyA"].CreateReader());
    BaseClassB b = serializer.Deserialize<TB>(obj["MyB"].CreateReader());
    return new Stuff { MyA = a, MyB = b };
}
```

I can prepopulate Stuff with uninitialized instances of concrete types and do a custom converter that uses the types of what's already there. That has the advantage that a Stuff object can be part of something bigger, and you can serialize the whole blob.

```
Stuff myStuff = new Stuff { MyA = new SpecificA(), MyB = new SpecificB() };
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, myStuff);

[JsonConverter(typeof(StuffConverter)]
public class Stuff {
    ...

public class StuffConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        BaseClassA a = serializer.Deserialize(obj["MyA"].CreateReader(), ((Stuff)existingValue).MyA.Type);
        BaseClassB b = serializer.Deserialize(obj["MyB"].CreateReader(), ((Stuff)existingValue).MyB.Type);
        return new Stuff { MyA = a, MyB = b };
    }
}
```

I can deserialize lazily, by instead defining `Stuff` with accessors for the real data

```
public class Stuff {
    public JToken JsonA;
    public JToken JsonB;

    public BaseClassA GetMyA<T>() where T: BaseClassA { ... }
    public BaseClassB GetMyB<T>() where T: BaseClassB { ... }
}
```

Okay, so now for the trickier part. Sometimes when I deserialize I will only know what subclass to expect for MyA, but not for MyB. In this case I also don't expect to access MyB, but I do want it preserved if I serialize back again. The third method will work fine for this, and the second could probably be modified to handle it.

Anyone had this issue before and found a good solution for it?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you try `Stuff myStuff = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Stuff>(json);`? Why did that not work?

Comment: If you are properly following the rules of inheritance, it shouldn't matter if deserialization happens to the base class, because the base class should still be a valid inherited class, and thus can be casted when you use it.  If the data that Json.NET received can be deserialized to a given type, then that is correct for the object it received.  If that doesn't work with your program, then you shouldn't be using inheritance in the way you are using it.

Comment: Doesn't work: Stuff myStuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(json); SpecificA a = (SpecificA)myStuff.MyA;